# Use AirDrop between iPhone and older Macs (need "Don't see who you're looking for?" button on Mac)

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, mac, bluetooth, airdrop

I have a new Mac Mini, an old MacBook (which supports AirDrop but has on old Bluetooth module) and an iPhone.

When I need to AirDrop between my macs, in Mac Mini's AirDrop panel appear a button "Don't see who you're looking for?" which allow to work even with Macs with old Bluetooth module and Macs see each other.

Now I need to AirDrop between my MacBook and iPhone but, on my iPhone I can't find the "Don't see who you're looking for?" button so AirDrop doesn't work.

I tried [this](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_enable_airdrop_older_mac) but it doesn't work...

Is there a way to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apple Support:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144)

> What you need To share content with AirDrop, both people need one of
>   these devices using iOS 7 or later, or a Mac with OS X Yosemite:
>
> - iPhone 5 or later
> - iPad (4th generation) or later
> - iPad mini
> - iPod touch (5th generation or later)
>
> System Requirements
>
> To see if your Mac works with AirDrop, make sure you’re in the Finder
>   by clicking the desktop (the background area of your screen), or by
>   clicking the Finder icon in the Dock. Then, check to see if AirDrop is
>   listed as an option in the Go menu. If you don't see AirDrop listed,
>   your Mac doesn't support this feature.
>
> In order to transfer files between a Mac and and an iPhone, iPad or
>   iPod touch
>
> - Your iOS device needs to include a lightning connector
> - Your iOS device needs iOS 7 or later installed
> - **Your Mac needs to be a 2012 or later model with OS X Yosemite installed**
> - Your Mac and iOS device both need bluetooth and Wi-Fi turned on. You do not have to be connected to a specific Wi-Fi network.
>
> ***The Mac Pro (Mid 2012) does not support AirDrop with iOS devices.***
>
> To transfer files between two Mac computers, you need the Mac models
>   listed below with Wi-Fi turned on and OS X Lion or later installed.
>   MacBook Pro (Late 2008 or newer)** MacBook Air (Late 2010 or newer)
>   MacBook (Late 2008 or newer)** iMac (Early 2009 or newer) Mac Mini
>   (Mid 2010 or newer) Mac Pro (Early 2009 with AirPort Extreme card, or
>   Mid 2010)
>   **The MacBook Pro (17-Inch Late 2008) and the white MacBook (Late 2008) do not support AirDrop.
>
> For help identifying your Mac, choose About This Mac from the Apple
>   menu. You can refer to the Apple Support website to find out if your
>   iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch includes a lightning connector.

So, sadly, there is no known hack to make it work with iOS devices and older Mac's.  Would be a great feature though!

Answer (score 8):

There are two versions of AirDrop. The Mac-to-Mac AirDrop that was introduced in Lion works with old Bluetooth modules. The Mac-to-iDevice AirDrop that was introduced in Yosemite only works with newer modules (2012 or later). If you really want to get Mac-to-iDevice AirDrop, you'll need to either upgrade your AirPort card or get a dongle. [Continuity Activation Tool](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool) is a great app for enabling that feature, and they made a handy chart telling you what hardware you need to put on your computer to make it work with Mac-to-iDevice AirDrop.

[image: Compatibility chart]

Comment: Great chart!  + from me

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that this is a 7 year old entry, there is a way, today, to create an Air Drop connection with your new iPhone (tested with a 12) and an old Mac (Mac Mini Late 2012). The key is the WiFi signal. Trying to connect with a 5G sig won't work. If your WiFi router allows a 2.4, log both machines into that. Worked for me.